# How to mock View in Laravel 4

Tags: unit-testing, laravel-4

I'm trying to mock view in my test but getting error. 
This is simple test I'm trying to run.

```
    $this->repositoryMock->shouldReceive('paginateAll')->once()->andReturn('foo');
    View::shouldReceive('make')->with('admin.city.index')->once();
    $this->call('GET', '/admin/city');
```

But after running test I'm getting error

```
BadMethodCallException: Method Mockery_2_Illuminate_View_Environment::share() does not exist on this mock object
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what was wrong here. 
I've used `View::share(...)` method inside of controller's constructor. That was the reason why Laravel throwed an exception. I've simply didn't missed to mock this portion.